# Two joins on single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1
id    acc    offacc    debit    credit
1     43     44        12.2     0

Table2
id    dispval
43    ub01
44    cust02
```

How can I get this in Single Row:

```
id    acc    offacc    debit    credit
1     ub01   cust02    12.2     0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use table alias

```
select t1.id, t2a.dispval as acc, t2b.dispval as offacc, t1.debit, t1.credit
from   Table1 as t1
       inner join Table2 as t2a on t2a.id = t1.acc
       inner join Table2 as t2b on t2b.id = t1.offacc
```

Comment: This worked for me as I have more joins above and below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to join:

```
select id,
       (select dispval from Table2 where id = [t1].acc) as acc,
       (select dispval from Table2 where id = [t1].offacc) as offacc,
       debit,
       credit
from Table1 [t1]
```

Comment: I think downvote is because you did not take care of offacc

Answer (score 2):

Consider using LEFT JOIN twice on the table1 like below

```
select 
t1.id,
acc=t2.dispval,
offacc=t3.dispval,
t1.debit,
t1.credit
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2 on t1.acc=t2.id
     Table2 t3 on t1.offacc=t3.id
```